# Is there a way to apply worksheetfunctions in VBA directly on MULTIPLE destination cells in one go?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a proces that involves a sumifs function with multiple arguments applied on a large range for many cells. The end product should involve cells containing only values. An excel user would:

1. Type the formula.
2. Copy this to all cells in the table.
3. Copy all cell and replace with only values.
   (1st method below)

I usually like to avoid such visible intermediate steps in the spreadsheet in vba by copying all cells to a variant, doing the calculations (making use of Excel's own functions 'application.worksheetfunction'), and pasting the variant back to the range (2nd method below). Using such method, there's less chance of user interference during the calculations and it is usually quite efficient as well. However, I do not seem to be able to beat the performance of emulating the Excel user method using variants. In fact, on a large scale it gets much slower.

`

```
Sub countif_2methods()
    Range("A1") = "Marty"
    Range("A2") = "Marty"
    Range("A3") = "Emmet"
    Range("A4") = "Emmet"
    Range("A5") = "Biff"
    
    '1st method
    With Range("B1")
        .Formula2R1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C1,R[]C1)"
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B5")
    End With
    With Range("B1:B5")
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    '2nd method
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Range("B1:B5")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        v(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.countif(Range("A:A"), Range("A" & i))
    Next i
    Range("B1:B5") = v
    
End Sub
```

`

Is there some way to apply the application.worksheetfunction directly on the entire destination range in a manner at least as efficient as "writing_formula -> copy to other cells -> copy and paste as values" (1st method)?

I tried the 2 methods described on a large scale. For a searchrange of 35k cells, destination range of 3k cells using a sumifs function with 6 arguments, the 1st method was 10 times as fast as doing the calculations inside the variant.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the formula to the entire range in one operation and assigning the ranges value to itself yields the best results using a formula.  But don't forget to optimize the performance by turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` and setting `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'3rd method
With Range("B1").Resize(5)
    .Formula2R1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C1,R[]C1)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

The fastest way to do the count-ifs would be use a dictionary to count the matches and fill an array to write back to the worksheet.

```
Sub DictionaryMatch()
    Dim Map As Object
    Set Map = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant
    

    '3rd method
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Data = .Columns(1).Value
        Result = .Columns(2).Value
    End With
    
    Dim Key As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        Map(Key) = Map(Key) + 1
    Next
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        Result(r, 1) = Map(Key)
    Next
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
         .Columns(2).Value = Result
    End With
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the '3rd method' is basically a much more failsafe version of the '1st method'. It avoids the risk of copying values before they have been calculated. It is as fast as well. Exactly what I needed. The whole proces for 8 columns now takes maximum 15 seconds. That is good enough for now. I might take a look at further optimization next year inspired by the DictionaryMatch subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee it will be faster, but you can do it directly like this:

```
Range("B1:B5").Value = Application.countif(Range("A:A"), Range("A1:A5"))
```

Comment: It seems brilliant and works very well at first. But once I had destination and criteria ranges of different lengths i could not make it work anymore. For instance:
Works:


Range("C2:C3083").Value = Application.SumIfs(Range("BA2:BA3083"), Range("AU2:AU3083"), Range("AO2:AO3083"))


Does not work:


Range("C2:C3083").Value = Application.SumIfs(Range("BA2:BA35277"), Range("AU2:AU35277"), Range("AO2:AO3083"))

Comment: It's interesting that you say the first one works, since it doesn't for me. In 2016 at least there appears to be a limit of 255 cells for the criteria.

Comment: Ok, I have tried that first one with up to 40.000 rows. Still seems to work. Running Excel 365 for MSO, 2022 version.